# When is numeric suffix L (long) needed?

Tags: c#

I know that something like `1.5` is a double, so you need to use the `m` suffix to assign it to a decimal.

```cs
decimal d = 1.5; // won't compile
decimal d = 1.5m; // will compile
```

Now, a literal like `0` is an int. But why can I just assign it to a long? Is there any difference between assigning `0` versus `0L` to a variable of type long?

```cs
long l = 0;
long l = 0L;
```

Comment: You should also try `double x = 0.0f;` that works fine. Along with `long l = 0;` it's a widening conversion. Those are allowed implicitly. Everything else not so.

Comment: This is probably because a default number is a Int which will always fit inside a Long. But if you create a Int n = 0L then you would get a error. Because a long can't always fit inside a int.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But why can I just assign it to a long?

11.2.3 of [the spec](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-334.pdf) states:

```
Implicit numeric conversions
The implicit numeric conversions are:
•   From sbyte to short, int, long, float, double, or decimal.
•   From byte to short, ushort, int, uint, long, ulong, float, double, or decimal.
•   From short to int, long, float, double, or decimal.
•   From ushort to int, uint, long, ulong, float, double, or decimal.
•   From int to long, float, double, or decimal.
•   From uint to long, ulong, float, double, or decimal.
•   From long to float, double, or decimal.
•   From ulong to float, double, or decimal.
•   From char to ushort, int, uint, long, ulong, float, double, or decimal.
•   From float to double.
Conversions from int, uint, long, or ulong to float and from long or ulong to double may cause a loss of precision, but will never cause a loss of magnitude. The other implicit numeric conversions never lose any information.
```

`From int to long, float, double, or decimal.` is the relevant one here. 0 is `int` by default, so it can be implicitly converted to `long`.

> Is there any difference between assigning 0 versus 0L to a variable of
>   type long?

They will behave the exact same. The IL is the exact same.